# Generate different Raster Graphics based on partial binary data

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-processing, raster

I have the following use case where I store image files in separate chunks as binary data and I want to display to the user an image for each individual chunk. The user in this case uses a web browser and I have to construct these images using javascript.

What I expect is to be able **to split an image file in n binary slices** and be able to **generate an image for each of those slices**.

One partial solution that I thought of was to serve the entire image to the frontend and display specific slices by using same principle as css sprites but this implies knowing the slice width and height and also the positions left-top in px.

What is the most efficient method of getting the expected result? Thank you

Comment: why do you say "binary"? images aren't binary, image *files* are binary, but you don't care how the images are stored, you care about displaying them... right?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I store every chunk as a blob, so it's binary. I want to be able to generate images containing the pixels associated with each specific blob.